# He is sitting on/in a sofa

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

> Sitting on a Sofa
>   Sitting in a chair

Why we say "in a chair" but "on a sofa"? I always heard "on a sofa."
Why this difference?

Comment: Related from ELU: [“Sit in a chair” vs. “sit on a chair”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72831/sit-in-a-chair-vs-sit-on-a-chair). Happily the people there agree with my guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can sit **on** a *chair*
- You can sit **on** a *sofa*
- You can sit **in** a *chair*
- But... you can't sit **in** a *sofa*

As to why... I'm only guessing but I think it's to do with an armchair, where you're surrounded on three sides (the back and both sides) which makes it "in". With a sofa, because the sofa is so large relative to you, you can't be "in" it.

Comment: You nailed it. You wouldn't say "in a chair" for a straight-back chair with no arm rests. You say "on the chair" in such a case. // Just another weird quirk in English.

Answer (score 2):

When one sits on the sofa **alone**, no matter what place one occupies, there's going to be **an empty seat** next to one, opening of the flat or slightly curved **surface** of the sofa.

When one sits in a chair (and the chairs are usually designed for a single occupant), on **all sides** except the front, one would have **walls/sides** of the chair itself.  So thus one is surrounded by the chair.

You could use "*on*" with a chair, if, for instance, you're describing the location of a magazine or a book left on the seat, because in such a case, there would be more room for other articles, and the book/magazine would not occupy **the entire** chair.